# What is this strange fossil I found?

Tags: fossils, paleontology

I found this weird fossil rock and I am wondering if anybody could help identify what could have made the imprint in it or what kind of rock it is?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a sand dollar fossil.  Note the pentagonal shape in the middle.

[image]

Source: [fossilera.com](https://www.fossilera.com/fossils/3-2-fossil-sand-dollar-dendraster-cluster-california)

Comment: I think you might be right, that is so cool! I did not think I could find sand dollars so far inland. Thank you for you help! :)

Comment: @Crozier inland today is not necessarily were the ocean was in the past. I have worked fossil seaway deposits in Colorado which is about as far inland as you can get today.

Comment: @Crozier the top of mount Everest is fossil-bearing limestone

Comment: That is pretty interesting! Thanks for sharing @John and Gimelist :)

Comment: @Crozier the western interior seaway is kinda cool, its one of the largest marine deposits on dry land.

Comment: I looked that up, pretty interesting stuff! Thanks for the info! :D @John

Answer (score 2):

I found out today that this strange "fossil rock" is actually a sea biscuit (common name) in the class echinoidea. Sand dollars are flat, but the sea biscuits are "puffy". I found this out in my zoology class!